# How can I retrieve only one object from an array with check boxes?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several check boxes and I have a function that should `console.log` the selected object from the checkbox but when I select only one checkbox it `console.log` everything and doesn't return the value from the checkbox

HTML:

```js
<ng-container *ngIf="(world$ | async) as world">
  <div class="language" *ngFor="let language of world.languages">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="get(language)">{{language.label}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Component:

```
world$: Observable<World>;

get(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

[Data from Firebase (world$)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbUDe.jpg)

How can I retrieve only the object assigned to the checkbox?

```
- [x] English <--- When checking this checkbox it should only console.log "English" 
- [ ] French
```

Comment: That is property binding [checked]. set it to true or false for initial value. your (change)="get($event, language)" for the changes and which language is checked. just read through the api https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to either use a `mat-selection-list` or a `mat-radio-group`

- https://material.angular.io/components/list/api
- https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview

MatSelectionList is pretty easy to use as you can bind it and easily get the selected values. Example:

Component Template (checkboxes are automatically rendered):

```
    <mat-selection-list #thingsList>
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let something of things" [value]="something">
        {{something.name}}
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

Component TypeScript:

`@ViewChild('thingsList', { static: false }) thingsList: MatSelectionList;`

Then to get the selected values, you can just do:

`this.thingsList.selectedOptions.selected`

I didn't write this stackblitz, but seems to demonstrate the usage in a sufficient manner. The only difference is they use `ngModel` here instead of using `ViewChild` like I used above. Same result though: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Do you know how can I make it look like above? {{name}} after the checkbox